# How to assign global instance in my local function

Tags: typescript

i am pretty new to typescript/Angular2. Let me sum up real quick what I'm trying to do with my method. I have a hard-coded XML data where I parse it to JSON, after that, I assign each JSON to a FormComponent object which has the properties of id, field, label. After assigning my object I push them to a local array. Here comes where I am stuck at. I want to assign my local(demoArray) to my global instance(jsonArray) but I get an error doing it like below. I have tried calling another function to assign it but I cannot access my global instance with this. So I would really appreciate it if you guys can help me with it. Thanks in advance :)

**This is the instance that I'm trying to access(the function and instance are in the same class**

```
jsonArray:Array<FormComponents> = [];
```

**Where I'm trying to access jsonArray**

```
parseToJson(){
    
    let xml = '<forms><id>1</id><field>text</field><label>Name</label><id>2</id><field>radio</field><label>radio</label></forms>';   
    var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
    parseString(xml, function (err:any, result:any) {
      let counter = result.forms.field.length;
      let demoArray: Array<FormComponents> = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
         const myObj = new FormComponents();
         myObj.id = result.forms.id[i];
         myObj.field = result.forms.field[i];
         myObj.label = result.forms.label[i];
         demoArray.push(myObj);
      }
      
      //console.log(demoArray);
      this.jsonArray = demoArray; //where I'm getting my error

      
    });

    console.log(this.jsonArray);

  }
  
}
```

Comment: Please see [mcve].

Comment: thanks a lot i will look in to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here: `parseString(xml, function (err:any, result:any) {...}`

Inside a `function`, `this` points to the function itself.
You may use `(err:any, result:any) => {...}` instead.

FYI: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: thanks a lot, i don't know why exactly that is the solution but I will look at the link you have given. Thanks a bunch again :)